# awk commands appear to be transposing

Tags: bash, csv, awk

OS X 10.9.5, Terminal ver. 2.4

I have a .csv file with about 100,000 rows and about 200 columns. I want to filter on columns and create a new .csv file with specified columns.

I've been reading some awk tutorials, but cannot seem to get even the most basic commands to work right. For example, to print the entire first column, I have tried this:

```
awk '{print $1}' oldfile.csv
```

But I only get the first value of the first row.

When I try this:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' file.csv
```

I get the entire first row.

How do I get columns instead of rows?

Edit:

Following the advice of those who responded, I did the following:

```
file file.csv
```

I got back `data`

I tried:

```
tr -d '\r' < file.csv > unixfile.csv
```

And then when I ran the awk commands got the same results as I did previously.

So I created a small `awktest.csv` file on my OS X machine:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1       2       3       4
1       2       3       4
1       2       3       4
```

Tried:

```
print -F"," '{print $1}' awktest.csv
```

and got back:

```
col1
```

Tried:

```
print '{print $1}' awktest.csv
```

and got back:

```
1,2,3,4l2,Col3,Col4
```

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Show a sample of the input file, and your expected output, in the question.

Comment: Since you're on OS X, make sure your file has unix style line endings (0x0a) and not Mac (0x0d). With the Mac line terminators, awk sees the entire file as one big line.  You can run the command `file oldfile.csv` to check.  If it says `ASCII text, with CR line terminators`, the file needs to be converted to unix.

Comment: Your input file was created on Windows and so has trailing control-Ms. Remove them with dos2unix or similar and then run your awk commands.

Comment: You can do what Ed is suggesting by typing this `tr -d '\r' < file.csv > unixfile.csv`

Comment: you are trying to separate your columns by , but your columns are separated by space, try my suggestion in the answer

Comment: There is simply something very wrong with the contents of your input file. You can use `cat -v file` to see control characters and then use a normal editor to remove them or create a normal text file using some tool/method other than however you have been doing it so far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing `awktest.csv` to `awktest.txt`, and when I ran:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' awktest.txt
```

I got the entire first column, which is what I expected.

I tried changing my original `file.csv` file to `file.txt`, but no joy when I ran awk. I did some Googling re: Mark Setchell's `tr` command, and found this variation:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < oldfile > newfile
```

So I ran that on my new `file.txt`:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file.txt > newfile.txt
```

And then

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' newfile.txt
```

gave me what I was expecting. Subsequent trials with more columns gave me exactly what I wanted.

Now to figure out what, exactly, the initial problem was, and why those changes fixed it.

Comment: Your initial problem was that file.txt has MAC line terminators ('\r'), but the default record separataor for awk is unix line terminators ('\n'). By translating the line endings of your file you got it to work as expected. To run awk on the original file, change the record separator like this: `awk -F"," -v RS="\r" '{ print $1 }' file.txt`

Comment: @jas is right and that explains why `file` told you your file was `data` because a file without a newline at the end (which you apparently didn't have) is not a text file. I would convert all the `\r`s to `\n`s rather than changing the awk RS though as though that will work for awk it will cause you problems with other UNIX tools. Just use `\n`s, not `\r`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem was that file.txt has MAC line terminators ('\r'), but the default record separataor for awk is unix line terminators ('\n'). By translating the line endings of your file you got it to work as expected. To run awk on the original file, change the record separator like this:
`awk -F"," -v RS="\r" '{ print $1 }' file.txt`
                    – jas